# Can you use IF ELSE statements in PostgreSQL Rule

Tags: postgresql

Can I do something like this, the error i get is?

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 5:   IF EXISTS(SELECT nr_albumu FROM roznosci.suma_ocen)
          ^
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE oceny_change_rule AS
    ON UPDATE TO dziekanat.oceny
    WHERE NEW.ocena > 3.0 AND NEW.ocena <> OLD.ocena
    DO
    (
        IF EXISTS(SELECT nr_albumu FROM roznosci.suma_ocen)
        THEN
            UPDATE roznosci.suma_ocen SET suma_ocen = suma_ocen + NEW.ocena WHERE suma_ocen.nr_albumu = NEW.nr_albumu
        ELSE
            INSERT roznosci.suma_ocen VALUES(NEW.nr_albumu,NEW.ocena)
        END IF;
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use SQL commands in a rule.

As SQL has no `IF` (only PL/pgSQL does) you can't use `IF` inside the commands for a rule.

You can put your conditional into a PL/pgSQL function and then call that function from your rule.

---

With the given example, you seem to want what's also known as `UPSERT`. If you create a unique constraint on `suma_ocen (nr_albumu)`
you could use an `insert on conflict`

```
INSERT suma_ocen (nr_albumu, ocena)
VALUES (NEW.nr_albumu, NEW.ocena)
ON conflict (nr_albumu)
DO UPDATE 
  SET suma_ocen = suma_ocen.suma_ocen + excluded.ocena;
```